# Is there any error when deleting a row (of character) in 2D array, with `strcpy`?

Tags: c++, arrays, strcpy

I am a newbie to programming. I write this simple code to delete a row (of character) in 2D array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define M_RW 100
#define M_CH 100

void ArrIn (char a[][M_CH], int &n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = ", i);
        gets(a[i]);
    }

}

void ArrOut (char a[][M_CH], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = %s\n", i, a[i]);
    }
}


void ArrDel (char a[][M_CH], int &n, int position)
{
    for (int i = position; i < n - 1 ; i++)
    {
        strcpy(a[i+1], a[i]);
    }

    n--;
}

void main()
{

    char a[M_RW][M_CH];
    int n, k;

    printf("Number of row: n = "); scanf("%d", &n);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n---\n\n");
    ArrIn(a, n);
    printf("\n---\n\n");
    ArrOut(a, n);
    printf("\n---\n\n");
    printf("Want to delete row: k = "); scanf("%d", &k);
    fflush(stdin);
    ArrDel(a, n, k);
    printf("\n---\n\n");
    ArrOut(a, n);
    printf("\n---\n\n");

}
```

After I compile it, I input some data:

```
+ n = 5;

+ a[0] = "Careless whisper";
+ a[1] = "I feel so unsure";
+ a[2] = "As I take your hand";
+ a[3] = "And lead you to the dance floor";
+ a[4] = "...";

+ k = 2;
```

I would like to see result as this:

```
+ a[0] = Careless whisper
+ a[1] = I feel so unsure
+ a[2] = And lead you to the dance floor
+ a[3] = ...
```

But, it returns:

```
+ a[0] = Careless whisper
+ a[1] = I feel so unsure
+ a[2] = I feel so unsure
+ a[3] = I feel so unsure
```

I do not know why `a[1]` loop many times.

---

Could you show me: What I wrong when using `strcpy`?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behavior

Comment: `int &n` is not valid C syntax. Reference arguments are only in C++.

Comment: Pass by reference doesn't work in C.

Comment: First time through the loop copies line2 to line3, and then line1 to line2. What it should do is copy line3 to line2.

Comment: You have the arguments to `strcpy()` backwards.

Comment: There's also no reason to call `strcpy()` twice. If you want to delete item 2, copy 3 to 2, then 4 to 3, and so on.

Comment: You still have the arguments backwards. It's `strcpy(destination, source)`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have the arguments to `strcpy()` backwards. The syntax is `strcpy(destination, source)`, so when you write

```
strcpy(a[i+1], a[i]);
```

you're copying from `a[2]` to `a[3]` on the first iteration, then `a[3]` to `a[4]` the next iteration, and so on. So this copies `a[2]` to every remaining entry in the array.

Change it to:

```
strcpy(a[i], a[i+1]);
```